# how to stop writer.writerows(all) from repeating the lines after finishing it

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I use this code to read tweets from CSV file and write the result in new file. it is working well but the problem is that the writer does not stop and repeat the line again and again please any help?

```
with open('D:\oopp.csv', 'rU') as csvinput:
    with open('D:/test8_datasets_output.csv', 'wb') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput,lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all=[]
        row = next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            features = get_features_from_tweet(row[0])
            result1 = classifier1.classify(features)
            result2 = classifier2.classify(features)

            row.append(result1)
            row.append(result2)

            all.append(row)

            writer.writerows(all)
```

OUT PUT:    [["Tesla years away from its goal of reaching Apple's market cap http://t.co/uv6q87moTt", 'pro', 'neg']]
[["Tesla years away from its goal of reaching Apple's market cap http://t.co/uv6q87moTt", 'pro', 'neg'], ['Apple $1 trillion stock market value could be years away http://t.co/twZmljm5y3', 'pro', 'neg']]
[["Tesla years away from its goal of reaching Apple's market cap http://t.co/uv6q87moTt", 'pro', 'neg'], ['Apple $1 trillion stock market value could be years away http://t.co/twZmljm5y3', 'pro', 'neg'], ['Apple has banned "bonded servitude" at supplier factories worldwide http://t.co/kcJGLtgMjF http://t.co/KCYwDyqBEU', 'in', 'po']]
[["Tesla years away from its goal of reaching Apple's market cap http://t.co/uv6q87moTt", 'pro', 'neg'], ['Apple $1 trillion stock market value could be years away http://t.co/twZmljm5y3', 'pro', 'neg'], ['Apple has banned "bonded servitude" at supplier factories worldwide http://t.co/kcJGLtgMjF http://t.co/KCYwDyqBEU', 'in', 'po'], ["Alibaba's Jack Ma seeks to reassure employees over U.S. lawsuits http://t.co/ykFribORTH", 'in', 'po']]

Comment: input: GM faces investor demand for slice of $25 billion cash hoard

Comment: output:GM faces investor demand for slice of $25 billion cash hoard ,pro,neg

Comment: i m conducting sentiment analysis that classify each tweet to related topic and the sentiment of it

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add information.

Answer (score 4):

You are appending to a list then writing that list *inside the loop*.

Rather than append to a list, just write each row separately with `writer.writerow()` (no `s`):

```
with open('D:\oopp.csv', 'rU') as csvinput:
    with open('D:/test8_datasets_output.csv', 'wb') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput,lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        row = next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            features = get_features_from_tweet(row[0])
            result1 = classifier1.classify(features)
            result2 = classifier2.classify(features)
            writer.writerow(row + [result1, result2])
```

Comment: this is not the correct answer and the result is bad and the problem is why the loop does not stop

Comment: @IbrahimDangou: then tell me more about your input and expected and why my answer is incorrect. It'd be helpful if you gave us a *reproducible sample* in your question, with expected output, so we can give you more meaningful help.

Comment: @IbrahimDangou: put such information in your question. Try to provide a *simple, small representative sample*, that reproduces the issues you see, don't put *everything* in your post.

Comment: hmmm knowing MartijnPieters I can assure you with some level of confidence any wrongness in his solution is caused by a lack of information from you(@IbrahimDangou) ...  the loop will exit once all rows from reader have been consumed

Comment: but does not exit . my tweets is only 40 and the result is over 700. and it should be exit in 40th tweets.

Comment: @IbrahimDangou: my code cannot possibly do anything like that. It writes one row per input row read.

Comment: @IbrahimDangou: perhaps you forgot to remove old code? I've given you more context; there should be *no other code* in the `for` loop or `with` suites.

Comment: @IbrahimDangou: my code provides just as readable a result as yours did, but without all the repeated rows. How are you trying to read the result?

Comment: i got it, the problem was in  writer.writerows(all) to be moved backward anly

Comment: @IbrahimDangou: you should not be using `all` or `writer.writerows()` at all; they are removed from my code for example.